# trying to find php library to convert pdf to chm

Tags: php, pdf, chm

is there any library or PHP project to manipulate pdf and change it into chm format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say very hardly. PDF is a document format that can contain all sorts of things. CHM is a structured help documentation format. Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I don't think these two mix at all, at least not in a way that you run a converter on a file and get a finished result.

What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i'm trying to convert pdf consist of css reference (mostly texts) into chm. and learn how the library do it

Comment: @justjoe I think CHM is just a bunch of HTML files essentially, so maybe the first step is to get the PDF contents into HTML and then into CHM?

Comment: @pekka, that's a software...i prefer do it via PHP or code something ;) by the way, today is my holiday. i would like do it using PHP. if it's help ;)

Comment: @justjoe as I said, I think you are best off taking the HTML detour, these are pretty complex things. Otherwise, start by grabbing the content from the PDF, that might already be work enough for a holiday :)

Comment: @justjoe Good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276028/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091700/how-to-extract-data-from-a-pdf

Comment: @pekka : yeah, i think you're right. btw, thanks for the links