# Zapier: How to get value from pdf file

Tags: javascript, python, zapier, airtable

So right now i want to make a zap in zapier. Trigger when new pdf file add to specific folder in google drive, after that i want to write the code (zapier support python or javascript) to get the value from that pdf file (Ex: Birthday, address, certificate, experience, etc) and update that value into airtable. But i don't know how to write code to get the value from the pdf file ?. Can someone help me in this? . Really thanks.
File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MKA9VLqeNcaLNxvHVyGtOG7D06pB6RcQ/view?usp=sharing (This is word file but it'll be convert to pdf through cloudconvert).

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time [getting the data from the original docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440170/get-docx-file-contents-using-javascript-jquery) than you would [getting it from a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937808/how-to-extract-data-from-a-pdf-file-while-keeping-track-of-its-structure). If you really want to parse a PDF, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675690/if-identifying-text-structure-in-pdf-documents-is-so-difficult-how-do-pdf-reade/).

Comment: Oh. In that case, i think i'll have to do the code to get the value form the word file first. After that i'll use cloudconvert to convert pdf later. But how to do it with js or python ?

Comment: That works. I'm assuming you have a bunch of already-filled-out files that you have to extract data from, right? If you're handing out blank docxs for people to fill out, making those fields into a web form and having people submit the data might be so much easier on you haha.

Comment: Yeah, webform is much easier to linking API with other site and update data. But is there anyway i can extract data form word file using code in zapier ?

Comment: ok. I'm looking to it. Really thanks

Comment: Looking into it, I would use the [New File In Folder](https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-drive/) trigger then use [javascript](https://zapier.com/help/code/) with Zapier to extract and send the data to Airtable. The first link suggested doxctemplater for extraction - I would look into whether it works in the first place, then if it does, whether it can be included and work with Zapier. Good luck! Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Ooh...[Python might be easier than Javascript](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html) for parsing the docx actually.